# Is there a way to find out what item is in the viewable area of a single selection windows.forms.listbox

Tags: c#, user-interface, listbox

I have a Windows.Forms.ListBox on my form, and I've set the SelectionMode to one (I think that's the default). I'm trying to get the item that's in the visible area, when a user scrolls up or down on the listbox, but doesn't actually select the entry that's visible.  Is there a way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: [ListBox.GetItemRectangle Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.getitemrectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You could also use [ListBox.IndexFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfw3x8dc(v=vs.110).aspx). The first Item index is: `listBox1.IndexFromPoint(new Point(listBox1.ClientRectangle.Left + 1, listBox1.ClientRectangle.Top + 1));`. The last item index is: `listBox1.IndexFromPoint(new Point(listBox1.ClientRectangle.Left + 1, listBox1.ClientRectangle.Bottom - 1));`. Doesn't matter if the last Item is not actually at the bottom of the `ListBox` visible area. It will return the Index of the last item in the list.